# How can I make sure my alignment is always right?

Tags: html, css, typescript

I am making a website with vite and Typescript. In my rocket-section there is a problem. This is my rocket section:

[image: Rocket section with good alignment]

The issue arises when I reduce the size of my screen, causing the text under the "Fusion Engine" section to jump for certain rockets. Since the text varies for each rocket, this jumping occurs inconsistently - affecting some rockets while leaving others unaffected. As a result, a vertical misalignment is created. Please refer to the illustration of the problem below.

[image: Rocket section with misalignement]

I've noticed that this problem occurs when the width is 541px or less. However, I understand that implementing a static fix might not be the most suitable solution. Is there anyone who can provide guidance on how to address this issue more dynamically and effectively?

Here is my Rockets.tsx and Rockets.css:

```
import './Rockets.css';

function Rockets() {
  const rocketData = [
    {
      name: 'CosmoJet Alpha',
      imgSrc: '/images/Rockets/1.png',
      description: 'Revolutionary fusion propulsion technology. Unmatched speed, performance and efficiency.',
      features: [
        { iconClass: 'fa-solid fa-users', value: '12', label: 'Passenger capacity' },
        { iconClass: 'fa-solid fa-gauge', value: 'Mach 10', label: 'Maximum speed' },
        { iconClass: 'fas fa-route', value: '5 million NM', label: 'Range'},
        { iconClass: 'fas fa-broadcast-tower', value: 'RocketComm Basic', label: 'Communication' },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: 'CosmoJet Beta',
      imgSrc: '/images/Rockets/2.png',
      description: 'Interstellar travel like never before. Hyperdrive technology for instantaneous jumps across galaxies.',
      features: [
        { iconClass: 'fa-solid fa-users', value: '18', label: 'Passenger capacity' },
        { iconClass: 'fa-solid fa-gauge', value: 'Mach 25', label: 'Maximum speed' },
        { iconClass: 'fas fa-route', value: '22 million NM', label: 'Range'},
        { iconClass: 'fas fa-broadcast-tower', value: 'RocketComm Standard', label: 'Communication' },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: 'CosmoJet Gamma',
      imgSrc: '/images/Rockets/3.png',
      description: 'Intelligent onboard AI for precision navigation through asteroid fields and complex celestial routes.',
      features: [
        { iconClass: 'fa-solid fa-users', value: '27', label: 'Passenger capacity' },
        { iconClass: 'fa-solid fa-gauge', value: 'Mach 35', label: 'Maximum speed' },
        { iconClass: 'fas fa-route', value: '43 million NM', label: 'Range'},
        { iconClass: 'fas fa-broadcast-tower', value: 'RocketComm Enhanced', label: 'Communication' },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: 'CosmoJet Delta',
      imgSrc: '/images/Rockets/4.png',
      description: 'State-of-the-art shielding technology to ensure passenger safety even in the harshest cosmic conditions.',
      features: [
        { iconClass: 'fa-solid fa-users', value: '38', label: 'Passenger capacity' },
        { iconClass: 'fa-solid fa-gauge', value: 'Mach 50', label: 'Maximum speed' },
        { iconClass: 'fas fa-route', value: '55 million NM', label: 'Range'},
        { iconClass: 'fas fa-broadcast-tower', value: 'RocketComm Advanced', label: 'Communication' },
      ],
    },
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Our Fleet</h1>
      <div className="rockets">
        {rocketData.map((rocket, index) => (
          <div key={index} className="rocket">
            <img src={rocket.imgSrc} alt={rocket.name}></img>
            <p>{rocket.name}</p>
            <span className="specification">Fusion Engine</span>
            <span className="description">{rocket.description}</span>
            <hr />
            {rocket.features.map((feature, featureIndex) => (
              <div key={featureIndex} className="additional-info">
                <i className={feature.iconClass} />
                <p className="value">{feature.value}</p>
                <p className="key">{feature.label}</p>
                <br/>
              </div>
            ))}
            <br />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Rockets;
```

```
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 4rem;
}

.specification,
.description {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
}

.specification{
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    font-weight: 550;
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
}

.description {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
}
  
.rockets {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 50vh;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 0 4rem;
    padding-bottom: 3rem;
}

.rocket {
    flex: 0 0 calc(25% - 40px);
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
}

.rocket img {
    max-height: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
}

.rocket hr {
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 15px 0;
}

.rocket p{
    font-size: 16px;
}

.key {
    font-weight: 400;
}

.value {
    font-weight: 700;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .rockets {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0 2rem;
        justify-content: center;
        padding-bottom: 2rem;
    }

    .rocket {
        flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 40px);
        margin-bottom: 2rem;
    }
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 541px){
/* The text jumps right now, so the text is misaligned*/
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, tables are pretty good at this, but you'll probably get more control using [CSS `grid` layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) for this kind of thing without having to resort to media-queries. It's definitely worth taking time-out to get to grips with `grid`.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px;
  grid-template-rows: max-content max-content max-content;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>rocket1</div>
  <div>some text</div>
  <div>some other text</div>
  <div>rocket2</div>
  <div>this text is very very very very very very long</div>
  <div>some other text2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is definitely better, but still not the best. Is there a way that I can maybe add a `<br>` when the text from other rockets takes 3 lines but from the first rocket 2 lines?